# How do I delete a single instance of an intermediate model in a Django Many-to-many (through) relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is a M2M relationship, that has the intermediate model 'Membership' (the intermediate model stores extra information about the relationship between a student and a course, using the 'through' keyword). In my case the extra relationship is the grade a student has in each of his courses. MY PROBLEM IS: I can't find a way in django to delete/remove only one of the relationships between one of the courses and the grade the student has.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Since 'Membership' is an intermediate model, it disables the remove(), that would be accesible in a normal ManyToMany relationship.

You can use the clear() method, but his would remove every grade the student has in a course relationship. For example: If 'Carlos' was in 5 different courses with 5 different grades for each course, and also some other student 'Maria'

c = Course

```
  c.members.clear()
```

would clear every grade relationship. You can see another example in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

And if I try to use the remove() method I get an attribute error:

m1 = 'instance of a Membership'

```
m1.remove()
AttributeError: 'Membership' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

In the django admin, I am able to remove a single 'Membership object'==='grade relationship' but I can't figure out a way to remove it on the shell or on my code that does't use the clear() method (which does't work form me cause it clears every relationship)

Please Help :///

Answer (score 0):

You should just delete the membership.

```
m1.delete()
```